# outputting a php function to xml.

Tags: php, xml

I have a Function (within the class Database)

```
            function locTo (){//return the location of the to currency
                $con = dbconnect(); //instantiate db connection
                $locationTo= mysql_query ("SELECT location  FROM Sheet1 where currency_code = '$this->to'", $con);
                $lol = mysql_fetch_array($locationTo);
                return $lol['location'];
                mysql_close();
                  }
```

when I call the function

```
$foo = new Database($from,$to);
$hey = $foo->LocTo();
echo $hey;
```

or

```
 $foo = new Database($from,$to);
 echo $foo->LocTo();
```

It out puts correctly.

Im trying to put into XML and im getting an encoding error.

This is my XML

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<conv>';
echo'<at>'.$timefrom.'</at>';
echo'<rate>'.$rate.'</rate>';
echo'<from>';
echo'<code>'.$from.'</code>';
echo'<curr>'.$currencyFrom.'</curr>';
echo'<loc>'.$locFrom.'</loc>';
echo'<amnt>'.$amount.'</amnt>';
echo'</from>';
echo'<to>';
echo'<code>'.$to.'</code>';
echo'<curr>'.$currencyTo.'</curr>';
echo'<loc>'.$locTo.'</loc>';
echo'<amnt>'.$convertedAmount.'</amnt>';
echo'</to>';
echo'</conv>';
```

Does anyone know why I am getting an encoding error? I have checked the source code and it gets as far as the location.

here is an example of the location out put.

AED to GBP

```
 United Arab Emirates
 United Kingdom, Crown Dependencies (the  Isle of Man and the Channel Islands), certain      British Overseas Territories ( South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands,  British      Antarctic Territory and  British Indian Ocean Territory)
```

Comment: What is the error? Does the various variables contain stuff that needs to be escaped?

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/xml, charset=utf-8'); before the first echo

Comment: @ZiTAL yeah I have that at the top of my php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend switching to (for example) [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) so your code would look like this:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->formatOutput = true; // Just for presentation, don't use this in real app
$main = $dom->createElement( 'conv');
$dom->appendChild( $main);

// Generic attributes
$main->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'at', $timefrom));
$main->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'rate', $rate));

// Fill form
$from = $dom->createElement( 'from');
$from->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'code', $row['from']));
$from->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'curr', $currencyFrom));
$from->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'loc', 'time'));
$from->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'amnt', 'time'));
$main->appendChild( $from);

// Fill to 
$to = $dom->createElement( 'to');
$to->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'at', 'time'));
$to->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'code', 'time'));
$to->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'curr', 'time'));
$to->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'loc', 'time'));
$to->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'amnt', '<img />'));
$main->appendChild( $to);

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

This should make your XML always valid. The result would look like (filled just with string `'time'`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<conv>
  <at>time</at>
  <rate>time</rate>
  <from>
    <code>time</code>
    <curr>time</curr>
    <loc>time</loc>
    <amnt>time</amnt>
  </from>
  <to>
    <at>time</at>
    <code>time</code>
    <curr>time</curr>
    <loc>time</loc>
    <amnt>&lt;img /&gt;</amnt>
  </to>
</conv>
```

Take a look at last `<amnt />` it's correctly "xml escaped", you don't have to worry about it anymore, but be careful when using `DOMELement->noveValue = html` AFAIK this doesn't escape your values.

And of course don't forget to set correct [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), use (before sending any output):

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml, charset=utf-8');
```

Also take a look at [14.17 Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) and [MIME types on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME).

Comment: @vzwick I worked with that quite a lot... And your approach would be better if he had to process LARGE amount of data and will require sequential data processing. And +1 for reminding me to send correct content-type to you :)

Comment: I have tried that and now im getting "Extra content at the end of the document" do you know why this would be?

Comment: @Will post your xml (what you will get when you display source code) and maybe your code (somewhere on pastebin.com or similar service)

Comment: @Will Do you have a closing bracket `?>` at the end of your PHP file? If yes, remove it. That's a constant source of trouble and might well be related to the *Extra content …* error you're getting.

Comment: @vzwick yeah I did have. still etting extra content at the end.

Comment: @Will post your codes or at least resulting xml, we cannot help you just out of blue

Comment: I re-wrote the DOM without the vars and it works perfectly. the first two vars go in fine. then when i try to put in the $from var it returns this message.  Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/conv/index.php on line 122

Comment: @Vyktor $from->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'code', $from));

Comment: @Will you're naming your database values the same as DOMElements? Fix it :) I've renamed it to `$row['from']`

Comment: @Vyktor oops yeah I have changed that haha.

Answer (score 2):

[htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is quite probably your friend, as in

```
echo '<loc>' . htmlspecialchars($locFrom) . '</loc>';
```

Also, as mentioned by ZiTAL, `header('Content-Type: text/xml, charset=utf-8')` before any output is a must.

Comment: I have tried this and it hasnt worked. im getting an encoding error but im using  charset=utf-8 :/